# C# lib install?

Tags: c#

I downloaded two different packages, they both came with an .XML and a .DLL file. I used some of their source code and couldn't get it to work (missing namespace). How do I install the XML file and the DLL file? I know the dll should go into system32/system but what do I do with the xml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to install the DLL at all, actually. Just add it as a Reference to your project, then use it as normal.

The XML file isn't specifically necessary. It can be used to generate documentation for the DLL, if you so desire.

EDIT: Also make sure that "Copy Local" (or something similar, can't recall the exact wording) is set to True in the properties of the reference. This will ensure that the DLL is in the same directory as your exe. Otherwise it probably won't be in the load path and then your app won't run.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put it on any particular place (that system32 comment is an older technology).

Based on the issue you mentioned (missing namespace -> when compiling), you just need to add the reference to your project (right click on project->add reference->browse->select the .net dll).